# Next.js: Classnames generated from SASS contains variable

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, sass, sass-loader

When I import a SASS file into my components (scoped), the class names include the variable name.

**components.js:**

```
import styles from './styles.module.scss'

export default function MyComponent(props) {
    return (
        <div className={styles.wrapper}></div>
    )
}
```

**styles.module.scss**

```
.wrapper {
    display: block;
}
```

The generated class is: `styles_wrapper__Y5YAC`

When I use CSS instead of SCSS, the `styles_` in the class name disappears. I have already tried to customize the class name via webpack, but it is defined in the `[name]`. So again, the class name includes `styles`.

```
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    webpack: function(config, {buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, nextRuntime, webpack}) {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: "style-loader"
                },
                {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: {
                        modules: {
                            localIdentName: "[name]__[local]__[hash]"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: "sass-loader"
                }
            ]
        });
        return config;
    }
}
```

I would like to remove the variable name (*styles*) from the class name.